# How to do arithmetic operations with BitSlices?

Tags: rust

Using the [bitvec crate](https://crates.io/crates/bitvec), say I have two `BitSlice`s:

```
let num1: &BitSlice = 10.view_bits::<Lsb0>();
let num2: &BitSlice = 9.view_bits::<Lsb0>();
```

Is there a way to run bit arithmetic operations such as `num1 - num2` with these?

I have the limitation of working in a `no-std` environment and the bitslices can be rather big so I cannot convert them to numbers, do the operation and convert back to bit representation.

Comment: Can you use nightly?

Comment: The problem is going to be that you will need to create an arbitrarily large `Bitvec` as the result of additions and multiplications, which will be difficult in no_std.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I would rather prefer not to since in the past I got incomprehensible errors from trying to compile for an embedded target with nightly. But please do share if you have an idea how to do this with nightly.

Comment: @PeterHall Actually I am only interested in subtraction in practice. But a solution which panics at an overflow is also acceptable for me.

Comment: So why not just subtract the bits using a long subtraction algorithm?

Comment: You can subtract in place, but you'll need allocation for not in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bitvec` used to include [addition](https://docs.rs/bitvec/0.17.4/bitvec/vec/struct.BitVec.html#method.add) and [subtraction](https://docs.rs/bitvec/0.17.4/bitvec/vec/struct.BitVec.html#method.sub), but [they were removed in version 0.18](https://github.com/bitvecto-rs/bitvec/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#018). Also, there was never subtraction on `BitSlice`, only addition. Although [it was mentioned they should be moved into a separate crate](https://github.com/bitvecto-rs/bitvec/issues/17), I was unable to find such crate. So, you need to implement it yourself.

The easiest (although definitely not most efficient) way is to walk bit-by-bit and perform the operation.

For example, addition (adapted from the code in version 0.17.4):

```rust
/// May overflow.
pub fn add_assign(lhs: &mut BitSlice, rhs: &BitSlice) {
    fn add_with_carry(a: bool, b: bool, carry: bool) -> (bool, bool) {
        let result = u8::from(a) + u8::from(b) + u8::from(carry);
        ((result & 0b01) != 0, (result & 0b10) != 0)
    }

    let mut carry = false;
    let extended_rhs = rhs.iter().by_vals().rev().chain(core::iter::repeat(false));
    for (mut lhs_bit, rhs_bit) in lhs.iter_mut().rev().zip(extended_rhs) {
        (*lhs_bit, carry) = add_with_carry(*lhs_bit, rhs_bit, carry);
    }
}
```

Note that you cannot prevent overflow unless you can extend the slice, and that requires `BitVec` and allocation support.

Comment: Thank you! Just one last thing. I cannot figure out how to call this function. `add_assign(&mut lhs, rhs)` fails. Could you give me a hand with that?

Comment: @jhk999 What are the types of `lhs` and `rhs`?

Comment: `let lhs = &mut bits![1; 5]; let rhs = bits![1; 5];`

Comment: You need `lhs` to be `bits![mut 1; 5]`. `&mut bits![...]` produces `&mut &BitSlice`. See [`bits!`'s docs](https://docs.rs/bitvec/latest/bitvec/macro.bits.html).

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I will add my own function for subtraction as well:

```
pub fn subtract(lhs: &mut BitSlice, rhs: &BitSlice) {
    let mut borrow = false;
    for (mut l, r) in lhs
        .iter_mut()
        .rev()
        .zip(rhs.iter().by_vals().rev().chain(core::iter::repeat(false)))
    {
        if borrow {
            *l = !(*l);
            borrow = *l;
        }
        *l = match (*l, r) {
            (true, false) => true,
            (false, true) => {
                borrow = true;
                true
            }
            (_, _) => false,
        };
    }
}
```

I can make certain assumptions such as the bit order and `lhs >= rhs` for my use case, so if you are going to copy paste this code please consider such cases as well.